# how to check if methods have been called jasmine unit test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner

I'm new to unit testing, and after reading the docs I'm still confused on how to do checks on asynchronous methods, as far as i understand I will need to use runs() and wait(). However, instead of doing that, I could use spyOn to check if the method has been called instead.

this is the code i want to test

```
  $scope.createMedicalServices = function(){
        if($scope.newTreatment.async_selected_treatment.id == null){
            $scope.newTreatment.description = $scope.newTreatment.description_no_id;
        }
        else{
            $scope.newTreatment.description = $scope.newTreatment.description;
        }

      $scope.newTreatment.no_cpt_code = $scope.newTreatment.no_cpt_code;
      $scope.newTreatment.cash_price = $scope.newTreatment.cash_price_input;
      $scope.newTreatment.average_price = $scope.newTreatment.average_price_input;
      $scope.newTreatment.service = $scope.newTreatment.async_selected_treatment.service;

      var returnPromiseObject;
      if ($scope.newTreatment.no_cpt_code) {
            returnPromiseObject = ProviderMedicalService.createNew($scope.newTreatment);
      }
      else if($scope.newTreatment.async_selected_treatment.id == null){
            returnPromiseObject = ProviderMedicalService.createNewCPT($scope.newTreatment);
      }
      else{
        returnPromiseObject = ProviderMedicalService.createExisting($scope.newTreatment);
      }

      returnPromiseObject.then(
        function (value){
          $scope.newTreatment.id = value.id;
          $scope.provider_medical_services.push($scope.newTreatment);
        },
        function (error){
          console.log(error);
        });
        };

  $scope.searchTreatments = function(value){
    return Treatment.find(value).then(function(values){
      return values;
    });
  };
```

and this is what i wrote so far, but its not much as i have no idea how to test it.

```
  it('search treament should have been called and return a value'),function(){
  scope.searchTreatments();

}

it('it should create medical service after submitting the form'),function(){
  scope.createMedicalServices();
  runs
}
```

Basically, I am content if the method just gets called properly, as the createMedicalService function is actually executed the moment the user clicks on the submit form, as its part of ng-submit on the html file.

Help and suggestions greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unit testing can be a little confusing at first. There are a few principles that help with unit testing.

Singleness of Purpose. A component should just do one thing. Consider breaking your code into smaller parts. Move logic out of controllers into factories or services. These can be tested individually.

Inversion of Control. Angularjs does a great job at providing IoC built in. Pass in your dependencies as stubs, fakes or mocks into your unit.

Only test the interface. It is a bad practice to test the internal call structure of a unit. This ends up not testing the functionality, but rather the implimentation. Instead think about this example.

You have a controller that gets a rest service passed in called nameService. This controller has a method called submit(first, last) that when called, should called the method post(args) on the nameService.

This would allow you to create a stub of the nameService, create a spy on the post() method and pass in the stub to the controller we are testing. Then you can simply call submit() on the controller and test that it called the service.

In essence, you test that if you input something into your unit, your unit will output it as expected.